# what scope must set with a registered app with clientsecret MSAL

Tags: adal, azure-ad-msal

I have succesfull used ADAL and want to upgrade to MSAL.
I used the follow code with ADAL

```
        var tenantId = "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx";
        var clientId = "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx";
        var clientSecret = @"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
        var applicationId = "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx";
        var authority = $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}";
        var ac = new AuthenticationContext(authority);
        var clientCred = new ClientCredential(clientId, clientSecret);
        var authenticationResult = ac.AcquireTokenAsync(applicationId, clientCred).Result;
        string authToken = authenticationResult.AccessToken;
```

With this code I get a valid access token to access the web app

With MSAL I don't know what to use for scope. The default graph scope give me a valid token but not  access to my application.

```
            IConfidentialClientApplication app = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create(clientId)
            .WithClientSecret(clientSecret)
            .WithAuthority(new Uri(authority))
            .Build();

        var authenticationResult2 = await app.AcquireTokenForClient(new []{ "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" }).ExecuteAsync();
        string authToken2 = authenticationResult2.AccessToken;
```

Where can I find a valid scope for the application.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The scope is in the form resource/.default. In this case

```
            var authenticationResult2 = await app.AcquireTokenForClient(new []{ applicationId + "/.default" }).ExecuteAsync();
```